# How do I reload a ResourcePool after the Resource is used up?

Tags: anylogic, logistics

Following problem: I have 10.000 RFID Chips in a ResourcePool. When they are used up I need 10 seconds to reload the machine with 10.000 RFID Chips again. Since I'm a beginner my question is: what code do I need to write where in the properties of the ResourcePool?

Comment: To clarify: are used RFID chips supposed to come back to the ResourcePool at some point or is it that once they're seized they're gone and will never be released?

Comment: Yes sorry for not clarifying enough, the RFID-Chips are lost after they are used. So we will need to refill the machinery with 10000 new RFID Chips.

Comment: In that case, ResourcePool isn't the best option as it is an object explicitly created to model resources that are shared by various agents during the simulation lifetime. Perhaps [Match](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/processmodeling/match.html) or [Combine](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/processmodeling/combine.html) would be a better fit instead.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment: perhaps **ResourcePool** isn't the best option as it is an object explicitly created to model resources that are shared by various agents during the simulation lifetime. Perhaps **Match** or **Combine** would be a better fit instead.